# When icon comes to circle it should be clickable

Tags: android, graphics

I am desinging a page circle layout wheel menu bar. I have some icons in it. When a icon(image) come to circle, that icon should be become clickable.How can I do this when icon circled and icons come in circle how can i do click able this pink image only at circle

**I want pink image will be background and icon comes circle it should be click able only at circle**

**I used gama_wheel_v1.0.jar**
so do you know any library example could you help me

İcons:
[image]

Selected icon will come to this circle:
[image]

This is my mainactivity :

```
 import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);               
            init();
        }

        private Wheel wheel;
        private Resources res; 
        private int[] icons = { 
                R.drawable.icon00, R.drawable.icon01, R.drawable.icon02, 
                R.drawable.icon03, R.drawable.icon04, R.drawable.icon05, 
                R.drawable.icon06, R.drawable.icon07, R.drawable.icon08, 
                R.drawable.icon09, R.drawable.icon10, R.drawable.icon11 };

        private void init() {
            res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
            wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);

            wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
            wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);

                }

            private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(int[] data) {
            Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                ret[i] = res.getDrawable(data[i]);
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

And this is my xml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, GAMA!" />

    <com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel
        android:id="@+id/wheel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/Adsız"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  If you're wanting to know when a user taps your wheel view, look at setOnClickHandler

Comment: When posting code, please just copy/paste it in, rather than posting screenshots. It makes it easier for others to copy it into their IDE if needed to test things.

Comment: ok ı changed it. Sory my bad english